# Explanation of conversion of CNF to imperative normal form in 2-SAT problem?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, boolean-algebra

so this question might seem dumb to many of you but I'm finding it somewhat hard to grasp the conversion of a CNF clause to INF one.

I was going through [this article](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/2SAT.html) where it states:

> First we need to convert the problem to a different form, the so-called implicative normal form. Note that the expression a∨b is equivalent to **¬a⇒b∧¬b⇒a** (if one of the two variables is false, then the other one must be true).

Can somebody explain how do we get to this result/how does this conversion makes sense? I've no idea what that " => " sign means, either. Thanks in advance!

**Update 1**: If in doubt with different logical symbols, refer to this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logic_symbols).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_(rule_of_inference)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=>` is implication, with the truth table:

```
A B | A => B
----+-------
F F |   T
F T |   T
T F |   F
T T |   T
```

In fact, you can show that `a => b` is equivalent to `~a \/ b`. (Just fill out the truth tables.)

Now, we have:

```
  ~a => b 
= ~(~a) \/ b
= a \/ b
```

So, it's even stronger: `a \/ b` is equivalent to `~a => b`. You can similarly show it is also equivalent to `~b => a`; so taking the conjunction is redundant perhaps, but it doesn't change the equivalence.

If in doubt, always draw the full truth tables, assuming you have 4-5 variables it would be very educational. If you have more variables, use a SAT/SMT solver to prove equivalence. That's what they are good for.

Comment: Also from wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional It merely means "if p is true then q is also true" such that the statement p → q is false only when p is true and q is false.